# MediaElement.js player track bar jumps near the end of audio

Tags: mediaelement.js

I've managed to get media element.js working but when the music gets near the end the current bar jumps and doesn't complete all the way to the end. I haven't a clue whats going on with it.

I've got it uploaded here if it helps out. (its at the bottom)

http://sites.lukespoor.me/mediaelement/blog.html